# How to fetch values in array in C?

Tags: c, function

I want the result to be appear as

```
Here is your name: John
Here is your Date of birth: 02/02/1999
```

Although name, DOB are present in array and I am successfully fetching those values of name, dob etc. But the problem is that it is giving me this problem.

```
Here is your name: John
Here is your name: 02/02/1999
Here is your name: 442342352
```

Means with every value it is giving me only name, although everything is present in array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    const char listings[5][51] = {"Name", "Date of birth","ID card number","Phone number","Address"};
    FILE * fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt","r");
    char ch[100];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        if(fr != NULL){
            while((ch[index] = fgetc(fr)) != EOF){
                if(ch[index] == ' ') {
                    ch[index] = '\0';
                    printf("Here is your %s: %s\n",listings[i], ch);
                    index = 0;
                }
                else {
                    index++;
                }
            }
            fclose(fr);
        }
        else{
            printf("Unable to read file.");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't close the file inside the `for` loop.

Comment: The `for` loop should be inside the `if (fr != NULL)` test, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through the whole at once, your 'i' is never incremented. Then, increment it inside the while loop.

```
while((ch[index] = fgetc(fr)) != EOF){
       if(ch[index] == ' ') {
           ch[index] = '\0';
           printf("Here is your %s: %s\n",listings[i], ch);
           index = 0;
           i++;
       }
       else {
             index++;
       }
   }
```

Don't forget to erase the for loop.

Comment: `i` is the iteration variable of `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)`

Comment: You need a different variable for the index into `listings`.

Comment: If for loop erased then how will I put value of **i**?

Comment: Just initialize it with zero out of the while loop.